# Django-admin.py startproject --template with templatetags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I often build and deploy Django CMS sites. I have come to realize that the django-admin.py startproject command based off of a template is the the best way to go for efficiency so I don't have to always repeat my setup steps.

I've built a small skeleton project for this and I have a base set of HTMl files in this project and I use the following command with the `--extensions` flag:

`django-admin.py startproject --template /envs/cms-setup --extension py,md,html project_name`

I have an issue though, when I pass the --extensions flag to the command I get an error saying

`django.template.base.TemplateSyntaxError: 'cms_tags' is not a valid tag library: Template library cms_tags not found, tried django.templatetags.cms_tags`

How do I make `startproject` with the `--extensions` aware of the HTML templates and it's template tags, is this possible to do or is there a workaround that someone can point me to?

Jeff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#templatetag is the solution for parsing out variable name with project name in html templates with the --extensions flag